# How many quantifiers are there?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

In *A Tour Through Mathematical Logic*, Wolf gives the following example in Section 1.3, *Quantifiers*:

> **Example 8.** The intermediate value theorem states that … $$\forall a, b, f[(a\in\Bbb{R}\wedge b\in\Bbb{R}\wedge a<b\wedge f \text{ is a continuous function from } [a, b] \text{ to } \Bbb{R} \wedge f(a) \cdot f(b) < 0) \rightarrow \exists c (a<c<b \wedge f(c)=0)].$$ So the statement includes eight quantifiers including the ones required to say that $f$ is continuous. Note that seven of the quantifiers involve real number variables, but one of them, $\forall f$, refers to all functions.

How are there **seven** quantifiers on real number variables? I see only three: two in $\forall a, b$, and one in $\exists c$.

Comment: They explicitly include the quantifiers required to say that $f$ is continuous, which are not stated in the formula. So you need epsilons and deltas and the definition to applies to all $x\in [a,b]$ and you need the function to remain bounded for all values in an interval. So that looks like four extras - but look back at how it has been formulated.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks! That makes sense. But are you sure that the number of quantifiers will be always four in any equivalent definition of continuity?

Comment: I haven't investigated the number of quantifiers necessary to defend continuity, and there are alternative ways of defining the concept. That is why I suggested you might see what the text you are using has to say about it.